# github for mac sync failed

Tags: macos, github, synchronization

I am using the github for mac app http://desktop.github.com/ and every time I try to sync a branch I get a `A network error occurred. We could not sync with the server.` Everything was working fine earlier and my machine other machine is able to run sync fine with the same app. I am not sure how to ge about debugging this.

Comment: GitHub has invalidated SSH keys today. Log on to your account for the project and re-approve the keys.

Comment: @RickStrahl Yeah just read the email after I posted this.

Comment: For future Googlers, the answer is the bottom result on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11856151/581766

Comment: @Fred that wasn't the answer for me. I signed out of my Github Desktop account, and signed back in, and then this error disappeared and I was able to sync again. Nothing else worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Found Out Why Just got this email from github, Crazy.**

A security vulnerability was recently discovered that made it possible for an attacker to add new SSH keys to arbitrary GitHub user accounts. This would have provided an attacker with clone/pull access to repositories with read permissions, and clone/pull/push access to repositories with write permissions. As of 5:53 PM UTC on Sunday, March 4th the vulnerability no longer exists.

While no known malicious activity has been reported, we are taking additional precautions by forcing an audit of all existing SSH keys.

## Required Action

Since you have one or more SSH keys associated with your GitHub account you must visit https://github.com/settings/ssh/audit to approve each valid SSH key.

Until you have approved your SSH keys, you will be unable to clone/pull/push your repositories over SSH.

## Status

We take security seriously and recognize this never should have happened. In addition to a full code audit, we have taken the following measures to enhance the security of your account:

- We are forcing an audit of all existing SSH keys
- Adding a new SSH key will now prompt for your password
- We will now email you any time a new SSH key is added to your account
- You now have access to a log of account changes in your Account Settings page
  Sincerely, The GitHub Team

--- https://github.com support@github.com

Comment: All of my SSH keys have been approved and I am still getting this error. This question is still unanswered and there is surprisingly little coverage of it on google.

Comment: Same issue on my end.

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved the same issue on a repo of mine. I had initially cloned the repo in Terminal with `git://github.com/djs070/reservedpaths`, before switching to Github for Mac client. I went to repo settings in Github for Mac and changed the Primary Remote Repository setting to the format `git@github.com:djs070/reservedpaths.git`, and was then able to sync to remote without any trouble.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't the approved answer. @Anders Kitson this solved the same problem for me.

Comment: Voila!! Voila!! Voila!! Voila!! That provides a much more consistent connection. Personally, mine was actually using https instead of git. Now i'm using the git@ syntax.